# Are ids in mysql guaranteed not to be repeated, even if rows are deleted?

Tags: mysql

Of course if I put enough rows eventually there will be a repeat. But let's assume I choose a big enough id field.

I want to know if I can assume that the id uniquely identifies the row over time. And if the client sends me an id I want to be able to determine what row it refers or if the row was deleted (or if it is a fake id, but in that case I will not care telling, wrongly, that the row was deleted).

Please refer also to the following: if I restart the database, or backup and restore - will it be continue creating ids where it left - or may be it will decide to "fill in the holes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a "int not null auto increment primary key" that you never reset, then yes IDs will not be reused.

However, this raises an interesting question - what happens *if* you happen to reuse an old ID (even though it won't happen by default in MySQL, but the human factor always counts) ?

If your database is properly normalized, cascaded *and* constrained your application should be able to handle the reuse of an ID.

**Edit** (since you edited your post, I'll flesh out my answer), about this quote: *"And if the client sends me an id I want to be able to determine what row it refers or if the row was deleted"*. It's always possible to determine what row an ID belongs to if it's not deleted (kind of vital to be able to extract information out of your database).

**However** if the row the id refers to is deleted, then it's *not* possible to determine what row it belongs to... since it's not there. If you need this I would advice you to implement some type of auditing functionality, preferably by [triggers](http://www.google.com/search?hl=sv&q=mysql+triggers+to+audit&btnG=S%C3%B6k&lr=) .

Comment: and when do I reset it? Is it something I do with a command or can it happen as a side effect of something.

Comment: Well, it's not something that will likely happen - but it is possible through various sql commands in mysql.

Comment: If you're not certain about when to reset, then don't reset it. Automatically generated ids are not meant to be be meaningful nor reusable.

Comment: Usually an auto_incremement column will also be a primary key would it not. So in that case you wouldn't have to worry about manually re-using an ID, right?  You'd get a clear duplicate value on primary key error.

Answer (score 2):

The current autoincrement value is preserved across backup/restores via an extra attribute attached to the table.  You can see it in a dump just after the ENGINE=:

```
mysql> create table foo ( bar int(11) primary key auto_increment );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into foo () values (), (), (), ();
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table foo \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: foo
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `bar` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`bar`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can reset it using "ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=", but it looks to me like
the attribute value is ignored if it isn't more than the maximum existing id when you do an insert.

Answer (score 0):

also note that the described behaviour of not reusing a previously used ID is valid for the MyISAM engine, but actually is not valid for all available engines.